Element positioning with dialog/modal css
Is it possible to place an element on top of a Dialog modal that is not a direct child of the dialog html/css/javascript?
When I am using the dialog element provided by html as a modal with the showModal() and close() javascript/jquery. I cannot seem to place any elements on top of the dialog or dialog backdrop no matter how high I set the z-index. is there a way to do this? Below is a simplified version of the problem:


const dialog = $("#dialog");
const openDialogBtn = $("#openDialog");
const closeDialogBtn = $("#closeDialog");

openDialogBtn.on("click", function() {
  dialog[0].showModal();
});

closeDialogBtn.on("click", function() {
  dialog[0].close();
});
.onTop {
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px; 
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
}

dialog::backdrop {
  z-index: 999;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0,0.8);
}

dialog {
  z-index: 998;
}
<div class="onTop" open>should be above/on top of dialog</div> 
<button id="openDialog">open</button>
<dialog id="dialog">
  <button id="closeDialog">close</button>
  dialog
</dialog>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>




No, that is not possible, because it is the point of a modal, that it places on top of everything else. If you want a dialog that is not modal, then use the show method instead. (But then interaction with anything outside the dialog will still be possible.)

No, that is not possible, because <dialog> element is like a new window over all  HTML page elements

Yeah, it seems there is no way around this. I ended up rebuilding a modal without the dialog element to avoid this problem. Thanks

u maynot use that z index thats already fixed,
and dialog tag centered by using margin so u just need to decrease margin in that direction that u wanna be placed that dialog in your case is margin-top: 0;
and dont forget using id it connect by it

showModal() renders the <dialog> element in the top layer, which is placed above all content.
Instead use show() to render it within the page layer.
However, then document flow will affect the dialog and other items will be interactable, so you will probably need to use a combination of position: fixed or position: absolute elements to get your desired outcome.
Alternatively, you could use showPopover() on a parent element to place more than just the dialog in the top layer.
